# return array of key obj in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

i have this array obj:

```
var scenari =[
    {pos:'i4y',azione:('persa','avanti','indietro'),'peso':(0.3,0.4,0.3)},
    {pos:'g4r',azione:('persa','avanti','indietro'),'peso':(0.3,0.4,0.3)}
];
```

How to retrieve the array in key azione?
i try this but is print only 'indietro' and not array

```
console.log (scenari[0]['azione']);//indietro
```

Comment: I would say, invalid json or object structure. Parenthesis on your "so called" array, are wrong.

Comment: You are using `(` and `)` instead of `[` and `]`. The key `azione` is not a JS array.

Comment: `()` are invalid. Need to be`[]`

Comment: The syntax is perfectly valid, the only problem is -- its not used to define an array.

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses not define an array and must be use brackets (`[]`):

```js
var scenari =[
    {pos:'i4y',azione:['persa','avanti','indietro'],'peso':[0.3,0.4,0.3]},
    {pos:'g4r',azione:['persa','avanti','indietro'],'peso':[0.3,0.4,0.3]}
]; 

console.log (scenari[0]['azione']);//indietro
```

Comment: You could also select with `console.log(scenari[0].azione);` because it is an object property within an array.. :/

Answer (score 1):

You are using () instead of [].

If you use () last value will be the value of key

```js
var scenari =[
    {pos:'i4y',azione:['persa','avanti','indietro'],'peso':(0.3,0.4,0.3)},
    {pos:'g4r',azione:['persa','avanti','indietro'],'peso':(0.3,0.4,0.3)}
]; 

console.log (scenari[0]['azione']);

//If you use () 

//Example:


var ke = ('d','e');

console.log(ke);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this issue because tuple javascript is  treating the data in () as a expression, so to get the result in the way you want you have to use [] or convert your data in string .